# using mesh analysis with capacitors and impedances

Tags: capacitor, inductor, analysis

My circuit analysis skills are a bit rusty; since, I been coding for a long time now. I'm analyzing a switching circuit's on and off cycle. I am solving for Vc2 in terms of D and ( 1 - D).

here is the circuit below :
[image]

On D, the SW2 and SW3 conduct. so, I made the following simplified circuit
[image]

Would the easiest approach be to use mesh analysis and treat the cap / inductance as impedance?

Comment: If the circuit deals with linear networks during \$D\$ and \$1-D\$, there is a discontinuity during the toggling event. If you need the control-to-output transfer function of this circuit, you should be skilled in the art of deriving the small-signal model of a switching converter. State-state space averaging (SSA) can be applied, but is quite complex. You can reveal one or two PWM switches in this schematic. However, I would recommend that you exercise yourself on simple sketches. Look at http://cbasso.pagesperso-orange.fr/Downloads/PPTs/Chris%20Basso%20APEC%20seminar%202013.pdf for instance.

Comment: this is CCM, Also for this coursera problem it adds : You may assume that the converter is ideal, and hence ignore all losses. You may also assume that all inductor current ripples and capacitor voltage ripples are small.

Comment: Regardless of its operating mode, CCM or DCM, you still have 4 switches and need to linearize this 4th-order circuit in one way or another. For instance, if SW3 is closed during \$DT_{sw}\$ while SW4 is open and then SW4 is closed during \$(1-D)T_{sw}\$ while SW3 is open, you already have a PWM switch model there. You can probably identify a second one. The thing is to draw the circuit state during \$DT_{sw}\$ and \$(1-D)T_{sw}\$ then identify the PWM switches. Once the PWM switches are placed, a quick sim tells you in bias points are ok then plug the small-signal sources in.

Answer (score 1):

Analysis with impedances assumes a sinusoidal steady-state operation. Since the voltages in your circuit will not change direction unless you switch the switches (thus changing the equivalent circuit), this analysis is not appropriate.

You'll need to analyze the transient behavior of your circuit, not the sinusoidal steady state behavior. You can do this with mesh analysis, nodal analysis, or an ad hoc combination of the two.